# How can I display buttons side-by-side in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I would like to display both of my buttons next to each other horizontally. So far I can only display them from top to bottom.

With the following code, what would I have to change ?

```
new Container(
    child: new Column(

      children: <Widget>[

      new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text("LogIn"),
        color:  Colors.blueAccent[600],
        onPressed: null,
        ),


      new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text("SignUp"),
        color:  Colors.blueAccent[600],
        onPressed: null,
        ),


      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Unclear. Can you edit your question to adds more details ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Column` is for items vertically arranged (hence a column), you are looking for `Row`. Just replace `Column` with `Row`, the rest of the code is fine. You can also use an `Expanded` if you want to fill all the available space.

Comment: I have 7 buttons in a row. A row can have only 2-3 buttons as per available width of mobile. Kindly suggest me how can I wrap multiple buttons in row automatically? Thank you.

Comment: @Kamlesh that sounds like a gridview to me:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists

Answer (score 14):

```
Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                ...
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                ...
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                ...
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: I have 7 buttons in a row. A row can have only 2-3 buttons as per available width of mobile. "Wrap" solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Wrap has alignment attribute but it is not capable to use full of out width then wrap the all the button align center. This is big issue for me. Still searching another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a column with text in it, and you want two buttons below that text right next to eachother you can use ButtonTheme.bar

Below is some of Flutter's starting code with it. You could plug it in to the starter to see it in action:

Just paste this after the second new text (the one with $counter in it)

```
        new ButtonTheme.bar(
        child: new ButtonBar(
        alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
                new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                  child: new Icon(Icons.add),
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: _decrementCounter,
                  child: new Icon(Icons.remove),
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                  ],
        ),
        ),
```

Comment: I have 7 buttons in a row. A row can have only 2-3 buttons as per available width of mobile. Kindly suggest me how can I wrap multiple buttons in row automatically? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Rahul Srivastava",
            ),
            Text(
              "Varanasi, India",
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      var player = AudioCache();
                      player.play('abc.mp3');
                    },
                    child: Text('Play')),
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      var player = AudioCache();
                      player.play('abc.mp3');
                    },
                    child: Text('Pause')),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new Button(
            ...
            ...
          ),
          new Button(
            ...
            ...
          )
])
```

Answer (score -2):

Just replace Column with that Row in your code It will work.
Although I want to add some extra stuff here suppose that you have Column wrapped inside a row then how will you achieve that displaying of buttons side by side?

Simple just change Column to row n row to column as follows:

```
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    child: ...
                  ),
                    child: ..                  
                  ),
                    child: ..
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Invalid syntax...